# How to divide two Pandas Pivoted Tables to obtain a resulting Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, division

I have one Pandas pivoted tables with 2 values: cancelled and total orders (with months: 1=January, 2 February, 11=November, 12=December and countries).

*df_Cancellations_group_GEN1 = df_Cancellations_GEN1.pivot_table(index='country', columns='month', values=['total_orders', 'cancelled_due_to_partner'], aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)*

**Example:**

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doXLG.png)

I want to have a third group which is the division of cancelled_due_to_partner/total_orders (same structure month/country). It could be aggregated to this dataframe or a new df, just need the code to get the division.

**Something like this**:

[Expected Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWghk.png)

I tried separating the df and diving, but dind't work.

*df_Cancellations_group_GEN1_cancel = df_Cancellations_GEN1.pivot_table(index='country', columns='month', values=['cancelled_due_to_partner'], aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)*

*df_Cancellations_group_GEN1_orders = df_Cancellations_GEN1.pivot_table(index='country', columns='month', values=['total_orders''], aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)*

--> *df_Cancellations_group_GEN1_cancel.div(df_Cancellations_group_GEN1_orders)*

--> **Dind't work**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably because your column names do not match. add `.droplevel(0, axis=1)` to the end of **each** of your `df_Cancellations_group_GEN1_cancel = ...` and `df_Cancellations_group_GEN1_orders = ...` lines, then, do `df_Cancellations_group_GEN1_cancel.div(df_Cancellations_group_GEN1_orders)` again.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondKwok! That was the issue. Problem resolved. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Good to hear that :)